# how to open a page in previous window?

Tags: html

I have number of buttons in my page. when one of them is clicked a popup opens.the user  browses some links there and click one of them. I want this webpage be displayed in the same page that the button exits. can you please give me a clue how I should do that?

Answer (score 2):

To access the parent window from a child window, use the parent property of the window object as such:

```
window.parent.location.href = "some URL";
```

The code of course should exist in the child window.